# frustrated db query and getvalue in a view after failure

Tags: php, mysql

After I print out a query of a list of user satisty some condition from my database I have got the following array

```
Array ([0]=>Array([users]=>Array([id]=>6 [username]=>sam [fullname]=>Sam Ho)))
```

But when I try to get the value in a view like 
`someone['fullname']` I have got nothing then

```
<?php
    foreach($users as $row)
    {
        ?>
        <h1>His name is <?php echo strtoupper($row['fullname']);?></h1>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use var_dump() to check the value of variables. Start with var_dump($row)...

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
$row['users']['fullname']
```

There's a second layer in your array.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the following should work perfectly.

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
   echo $val['users']['id'];
   // and so on
}
```

I am assuming `$array` as your main array of records.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    echo strtoupper($value['users']['fullname']);
}
```